# About Idle tasks in operating systems

Tags: operating-system

Every system has IDLE task which will be running if no other tasks are ready to run.So my question is , can IDLE task sleep?. My understanding is if idle task sleep then there is a chance of no task is  available for the cpu to run. Is my understanding correct? Can anyone provide some link which elaborate about this topic?

Comment: There's many more ways than just sleeping. But do note that most of the time, your computer is far from 100% CPU utilization - that's when there's no tasks ready to run right now, for whatever reason. In general, on modern systems it's usually a bad sign if some application *does* use 100% of the CPU when it's not actually doing anything to warrant that (in the past, it used to be the standard that you *always* run - there wasn't really a way to let the CPU "idle"; but that's already quite a long time ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could busy-loop at lowest priority, or loop around code that sets a low-power mode, or a loop around a 'halt' instruction that stops the core execution completely.

Sleep() is not approriate - the CPU has to enter a mode where it is unavailable to any other thread until an interrupt, and Sleep() does not perform that function.

Whatever the hardware supports.

As long as the CPU is able to respond to interrupt requests, any of the above would be fine.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your valuable answer. I understood the concept of idle task much better now..